# Catching TimeoutExpired exception in Python 3.3

Tags: windows, exception, python-3.3

Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I'm having trouble catching the timeout exception in Python 3.3, running on win7, e.g.

```
import subprocess
try:
   subprocess.call("ping -t localhost", timeout=3)
except TimeoutExpired:
    print("Timeout happened.\n")
```

The timeout works fine, and according to my pdb traceback, it says:
`"raise TimeoutExpired(self.args, timeout)"`

yet "except TimeoutExpired:" doesn't catch it. Also, TimeoutExpired is not listed as
a standard exception and comes out as a nameError.

If I try `"except TimeoutError:"` instead of `"except TimeoutExpired:"`, I don't get the error message, but in pdb, I get:

`"Uncaught exception"`

and the print command does not get executed in any case.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`TimeoutExpired` is not globally defined; use `subprocess.TimeoutExpired` instead.

Comment: Yeah, but subprocess.TimeoutExpired certainly should be derived from TimoutError ... not Exception.   I think that was an oversight

Comment: Perhaps. I could be wrong, but I think they chose to subclass from SubprocessError because this was not an exception within the context of the Python program itself but from the child process it was monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer:

```
from subprocess import TimeoutExpired
```

But I ended up with:

```
import shlex, subprocess; from subprocess import TimeoutExpired

proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("sleep 10"))
try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=5)
except TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()
    print("Timeout happened.\n")
```